# custom volume slider in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to improve my volume slider code that I made a while back. The problem I'm having is as follows.

**The problem**

1. When you click on the volume button and drag it the first time, the volume button jumps the the start.
2. Because of the first error, the mouse cursor doesn't line up at the centre of the volume button when being dragged.

This is probably due to the `event.offsetX`.

The first time you click the volume button and move it, The `event.offsetX` gets the offset of  *the position clicked on the volume button* to *the start of the volume button.

To fix this issue I added the variable `firstClicked`. However, this didn't fix the  problem.

```js
const volume = document.querySelector('.volume');
const volumeRange = document.querySelector('.volume-range');
const volumeContainer = document.querySelector('.volume-container');
const volumeBtn = document.querySelector('.volume-button');

const volumeRangeWidth = volumeRange.getBoundingClientRect().width; // This will be the volume limit (100%)

/*volumeContainer.addEventListener("click", volumeClick);

function volumeClick(event) {
  let x = Math.floor(event.offsetX);
  if (x < 0) x = 0; // check if it's too low
  if (x > volumeRangeWidth) x = volumeRangeWidth; // check if it's too high
  volume.style.width = (x + 10) + 'px';
}
*/


let mouseIsDown = false;

window.addEventListener("mouseup", up);
volumeBtn.addEventListener("mousedown", down);
volumeContainer.addEventListener("mousemove", volumeSlide);

function down() {
  mouseIsDown = true;
}

function up() {
  mouseIsDown = false;
  firstClick = true;
}


let firstClick = true; // this doesn't work
function volumeSlide(event) {
  if (mouseIsDown && !firstClick) {
    let x = Math.floor(event.offsetX - event.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect().left);
    if (x < 0) x = 0; // check if it's too low
    if (x > volumeRangeWidth) x = volumeRangeWidth; // check if it's too high
    volume.style.width = (x + 10) + 'px';
  }
  //  "firstClick" ignores the offset on the first click as it gives the offset of the volume button
  firstClick = false;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #2a2a2a;
}

.volume-container {
  padding: 40px 0px;
  margin: 0px 20px;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}

.volume-range {
  height: 5px;
  width: 250px;
  background: #555;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.volume-range>.volume {
  height: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  background: #2ecc71;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
}

.volume-range>.volume>.volume-button {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Volume</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="" style="padding-left:10px; background-color:dodgerblue;">
    <div class="volume-container">
      <div class="volume-range">
        <div class="volume">
          <div class="volume-button"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `mousemove` Event to volume button container, not itself, and then add `pointer-events: none;` to the volume button so it doesn't have its own separate mouse coordinates.

[See working demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NZMyXx)

Comment: "...so it doesn't have its own separate mouse coordinates." Can you please elaborate a bit more. I"m not sure I fully understand what pointer-event: none; is doing.